# Getting duration and creation date from video from ios library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video

I'm trying to select/compress a video from the photo library but when I go to get the duration and creation date, they both are returning null (for duration this defaults to 0.0 sec). I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)uploadPick didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

 if (CFStringCompare (( CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
 {
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    //Video Duration:
            MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                                   initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    VideoTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %.2f", mp.duration];

    //Video Creation Date
    NSDictionary *metadataDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:metadataDictionary.fileCreationDate];
    [dateFormatter release];
    VideoDateTaken.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date Taken: %@", stringDate];

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata), `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` is only valid for still images:

> This key is valid only when using an image picker whose source type is
>   set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, and applies only to
>   still images.

In order do get the metadata you want, use an `ALAsset` and the [metadata](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/metadata) method.

Comment: Before I fooled with videos, I uploaded photos and it didn't work either, but thanks I'm def going to look into this. Appreciate the feedback.